# Python: Submodules Not Found

Tags: python, importerror

My Python couldn't figure out the submodules when I was trying to import `reportlab.graphics.shapes` like this:

```
>>> from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
ImportError: No module named shapes
```

I have copied the `reportlab` package to **/site-packages** and I can import **module reportlab.graphics** successfully.

My Python version is 2.7.3.

Could anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dan-boa pointed out, you can add paths to the module search path, but since you can find the parent module, I doubt that this is your root problem.

Do you have some left-over installation of the module at another path? You can check the path where it is finding the parent package (reportlab) by executing:

```
import reportlab
print reportlab.__file__
```

If this is indeed the path you were expecting, then try this recursively with the the sub-modules, until you can see where the problem is. Perhaps, your package is corrupted? Try manually checking in the path returned if you can find the files/modules in question.

If this is not the path you were expecting, clean-up the installation from this 2nd path and try again.

Finally, in case you do find that it is a path problem, instead of adding the path each time using sys.path.append, you can add it to [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. That's a great way to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your sys path and if the directory of the module is not present then add it.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('PATH_OF_THE_MODULE')
```

As site-packages is already their in the sys.path, may be therefore the package was imported successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have already put it in the sys.path.

Comment: Instead of `append`, a `sys.path.insert(0, 'path')` might be more approriate in order to give it more precedence than the original one.