# ImportError: No module named '' when importing my own sub-package

Tags: python, package, python-import

By following the instructions in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555203/2071807) I've created a Python package with sub-package as sub-folders, each with a `__init__.py` file (which are all totally empty).

```
  top_module
     __init__.py
     module_a.py
        sub_module
             __init__.py
             module_c.py
```

I can import the top level module but trying to import a sub-module results in an `ImportError`:

```
>>> import top_module
>>> import top_module.sub_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sub_module
```

In iPython I can autocomplete `top_model.` to show me `module_a.py` but not `sub_module`.

Followed the instructions in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910407/2071807) but I just get:

```
>>> top_module.__file__
'top_module.pyc'
```

which is not terribly useful. Interestingly, `__package__` gives me:

```
>>> print top_module.__package__
None
```

I can do this:

```
>>> import top_module
>>> import sub_module.module_c
```

So why not `import top_module.sub_module.module_c`?

Comment: Which directory are you in when you are running these commands?

Comment: Good question. I'm either a) at the command line, in the top_module directory or b) in Spyder with top_module directory added to that IDE's "PYTHONPATH manager" tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked out what my problem was (and it's a pretty dumb error I'm afraid.)

I had my PYTHONPATH set to

```
/path/to/top_module
```

and was doing

```
import module_a
```

which of course worked. But trying to do

```
import top_module.submodule
```

didn't work because the `PYTHONPATH` didn't "know" about `top_module`, it was *already in* `top_module`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `from sub_module.module_c import *`

Comment: That works. What the heck is going on? Shouldn't I be able to do `import top_module.sub_module`?

Comment: @LondonRob I would think you could. Python's import system has always seemed... clumsy to me.

Comment: Thanks @Undo. I've adjusted my question to reflect this new information.